# Como alterar configurações do arquivo persistence.xml através de um arquivo externo?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsf, jpa, persistência

Queria saber como alterar a configuração do arquivo persistence.xml atraves de um arquivo externo. Estou usando JSF + JPA. Quero fazer isso para não deixar essa configuração presa no código fonte.

Alguém me da um help?

Comment: Daniel, que tipo de configuração do seu `persistence.xml` pode variar? Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Tipo mudar o url do banco, o usuário e senha, mudar de update para create, essas coisas.   Ex: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/almoxarifadome" /> mudar essa configuração por exemplo

Comment: Está usando o Tomcat 7, 8?

Comment: Estou usando Tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a melhor solução seja informar suas configurações de conexão no Tomcat, e não no projeto. Seguindo a [documentação do Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html):

Dentro do `Context` da sua aplicação, crie um `Resource` (atenção para o nome: `jdbc/TestDB`):

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
</Context>
```

No seu `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
    <description>MySQL Test App</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

No seu `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/TestDB</jta-data-source>
    <!-- Demais configurações pertinentes -->
</persistence-unit>
```

Desta maneira, seu projeto sempre será o mesmo. O que vai mudar é a configuração do seu *server/container.*

Comment: Tipo preciso instalar o banco de dados em um computador diferente. Neste caso preciso configurar a conexao. Essa configuração permite esta configuração?

Comment: Exatamente. Imagine que seu projeto `.jar`, `.war`, ou o que seja, será sempre o mesmo, mas em cada cliente - cliente no âmbito comercial - o banco de dados encontra-se em um local diferente, que, a partir de feitas estas configurações, você especifica no próprio Tomcat (do cliente).

Comment: Eu achei interessante esta opção. Mas não achei algo pra me auxiliar a fazer esta configuração no Toncat.

Answer (score 1):

O método `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` tem um overload que você pode passar um Map com as configurações do persistence.xml, aí você carrega elas de onde achar melhor (ex: um arquivo de configuração);

```
Map properties = new HashMap();

properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user-name");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");

Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name", properties);
```

Comment: Mas onde eu criaria este mapa, em qual classe? não entendi muito bem.. E onde eu indico o local do arquivo?

Comment: Tu não chama o método Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory pra criar a factory? Pode ser que você esteja usando alguma api que já faz isso pra ti, aí a minha solução não vai funcionar.

Comment: Sim. faço em uma classe específica.

Comment: Sobre o local do arquivo, eu uso uma variável de ambiente pra indicar o caminho.

Comment: Nessa classe que tu chama o Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nome-da-unit'), tu carrega as informações do map a partir do arquivo (eu uso a classe Properties do java pra isso), e chama Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nome-da-unit", mapComAsConfiguracoes);

Comment: Na verdade estou querendo usar um arquivo .properties para realizar a configuração do persistece.xml. Porem não to conseguindo ler o arquivo